# Prepare docker images tar for offline-environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, offline

FINAL EDIT: found solution - posted it as an answer, hope it will be useful :)

I am new to docker and wanted to achieve one thing:

I want to store my docker images to .tar in order to, later, launch d*ocker-compose up* in an envirnoment **without** the internet connection.

I've tried *save* and *load* options, but after loading, the images have no tags nor repository values - and later by launching *docker-compose up*, it **automatically** wants to pull the images - not use the ones I loaded.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I want?

EDIT: I haven't written it before - my bad - I can achieve what I want for a single image per command - by passing the image not by the id, but with repo:tag - unfortunately, I couldn't find the way to do it for all the images in one command - when I pass them by id with *docker save -o .\newTar.tar $(docker images -q)*, after loading them with *docker load -i .\newTar.tar* and calling *docker-compose up* they require pull

Comment: Show the commands that your have executed and their outputs

Comment: [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/): "Produces a tarred repository to the standard output stream. Contains all parent layers, and all tags + versions, or specified repo:tag, for each argument provided."

Comment: I've used docker save -o .\newTar.tar $(docker images -q),

the thing is when I precisely tar one image by calling it not by id but by repo:tag, then it loads properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your help - after sleeping some time I came up with the solution :D

because loading images works offline if you passed them with repo:tag, I use this save command:

*docker save -o .\firstTry.tar $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")*

then I load them with:

*docker load -i .\firstTry.tar*

Result: all images are saved in a .tar file, with possibility of loading them without pulling from the repo

Answer (score 2):

If you've saved from a tag (e.g. `docker save -o my-image.tar user9123/my-image:latest`), your image should load (e.g. `docker load -i my-image.tar`) with the tag

If that doesn't work, though, you can always use `docker tag` to name the image after loading.  For example, `docker tag 84fc2d8f0df8 user9123/my-image:latest`

Comment: The tag must be specified, otherwise all images with the `user9123/my-image` as the repository name are saved to the tarball.

Comment: Correct, and I've edited the answer to reflect that, but also not contradictory

Comment: thanks - I have also noticed that by saving it with giving repo:tag it works - but when I have x images, I would have to make a script for all the images, earlier I have tried docker save -o .\newTar.tar $(docker images -q), but because I pass images by id, then later they have no tag and force the pull during loading